# mgcv::gam overfitting

Tags: overfitting, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I'm trying to fit a cubic smoothing spline model to a longitudinal data using mgcv:gam. I have 30 observations collected from 5 subjects (A, B, C, D, and E) at 6 time points (0, 1, 144, 600, 1440, and 2160 hours). I fit the model as follows:

```
require(mgcv)
# data is ordered as A-t1, A-t2, ..., A-t6, B-t1, B-t2, ..., E-t6
data <-  c(4.9, 9.8, 6.7, 4.4, 4.5, 4.5, 4.8, 6.8, 4.4, 4.3, 4.4, 4.5, 5.2, 9.6, 5.9,
           4.5, 5.0, 4.7, 5.6, 9.9, 6.0, 4.8, 5.1, 4.5, 4.5, 9.2, 6.2, 4.9, 5.0, 5.7)  
subject <- rep(c("A","B","C","D","E"),each=6)  
subject <- factor(subject)
time <- rep(c(0,1,144,600,1440,2160),5)
# fit gam with random intercept and random slope
fit <- gam(data ~ s(time, k=6, bs="cr") + s(subject, bs="re") + s(time, subject, bs="re"),
           family=gaussian(), method="REML")  
# predict fit at a discretized grid  
t.pred <- seq(0,2160,length.out=100)  
fit.pred <- predict(fit, newdata=data.frame(time=t.pred,subject="C"), type="response",
                    exclude=c("s(subject)","s(time,subject)"), se.fit=F)
```

When I plot the predicted fit, it is clear that the model has overfit the data (observed data points are superimposed in black). I tried different parameters (choice of smoother, smoothing parameter estimation method, and gam.control options such as epsilon, maxit, mgcv.tole, etc.) but have not been able to fix this issue. I would appreciate your help!

```
plot(t.pred, fit.pred, type="l", lwd=2, col="red")  
points(time, data)
```

[image: Overfit model]
I'm also including a trellis plot of raw data, where observations are connected by lines, suggesting the correct trend for the fit.
[image: RawData]

Comment: You need to collect more data if you wish to fit such a complex model.

Comment: If I'm understanding the code correctly, you are using as many knots (`k=6`) in the time spline as you have distinct times.  That's meaningless: you might just as well treat each distinct time as a different factor--which demonstrates why any interpolation between those times is purely fanciful. Consider stepping back and thinking about what you *really* need to learn from this experiment.  If it requires more than six parameters to describe, you have little chance of getting reliable results.  (Limiting to three parameters would be advisable.)

Comment: @whuber: Thanks for the feedback. Isn't it the whole point of smoothing splines to place a knot at each unique value of time (instead of dealing with knot placement) and then use the second derivative penalty to minimize the resulting wiggliness?

Comment: The point is to use (far) *fewer* knots than points so as to obtain an economical but flexible description.

Comment: @SinaNassiri I think you might be confusing interpolation splines (a knot at each point, fits the data exactly with maximum smoothness) and smoothing splines (less knots than data points and knot positions are arbitrary, smooths data while optimising the trade-off between goodness-of-fit and wiggliness)

Answer (score 7):

The problem is what you mean by 'smooth' here. If you really want a curve that is smooth w.r.t. time and passes through the spike in the data at time 1 then it will have to vary enormously on the y scale. But in reality smoothness on a transformed time scale is probably what is wanted here. For example if we assume smoothness on the 4th root of time scale then the plots look much more like what you probably wanted (I've used uneven spacing for t.pred to make sure the rapidly varying region is well represented)...

```
fit <- gam(data ~ s(I(time^.25), k=6, bs="cr") + s(subject, bs="re") + 
s(time, subject, bs="re"),family=gaussian(), method="REML")  

t.pred <- seq(0,2160^.25,length.out=2000)^4 
fit.pred <- predict(fit, newdata=data.frame(time=t.pred,subject="C"),
type="response",exclude=c("s(subject)","s(time,subject)"), se.fit=F)  
plot(time,data)
lines(t.pred, fit.pred,lwd=2,col="red")
```

Comment: Smoothness on the 4th root of time scale is an interesting idea. I appreciate your input.